# What is this copper ring insert in my sharkbite supply valve?

Tags: plumbing, faucet, valve, plumbing-fixture, shutoff

I'm about to connect my new faucet supply lines to [this](https://www.lowes.com/pd/SharkBite-Chrome-1-2-in-Push-to-Connect-x-3-8-in-OD-Compression-Quarter-Turn-Angle-Valve/1000182669) new SharkBite™ valve.

The valves came with these copper rings and I am wondering what they are and should I leave them in when connecting the supply lines?

Also, do I need to use plumber's tape for this connection?

[image: Valve insert / ring on left]

Comment: That is a ferrule and it is used in a compression fitting, shark bite valves do not have ferrules. Are you sure that you have a shark bite valve ? , can you take a picture of the valve itself so we can determine exactly what you are working with.

Comment: Yes this is a sharkbite valve... with a sharkbite connect at one end and a threaded supply line connector at an angle. This one to be exact: https://www.lowes.com/pd/SharkBite-Chrome-1-2-in-Push-to-Connect-x-3-8-in-OD-Compression-Quarter-Turn-Angle-Valve/1000182669

Comment: Alaska man you need to make that an answer end when I get off the floor from laughing I will up vote. Yes it is a ferrule for use with the nut in the background  not a shark bite but a compression fitting normally used with copper pipe, if poly pipe is used there is an inner liner to support the poly when the seal is created. I see the op just posted a shark bite valve on the supply side with a standard compression on the faucet side. A standard 3/8 washer based flexible faucet hose can also be used if copper lines are not there.

Comment: So you have a valve that has a compression fitting on one side and a shark bite connection on the other side. Some more details on where are you are installing this valve and what it controls would be helpful but yes the ferrule needed on the copper pipe side of the equation to make a watertight connection.

Comment: Beal, I am NOT saying that THIS threaded end is a sharkbit connection! I said it is a sharkbite valve... which it absolutely is.

Comment: Alaska Man, I am connecting 3/8 supply lines that came with my bath faucet. They have a threaded nut connection. So the question again is, do I keep these ferrules in or remove them?

Comment: If you do not use that copper ring then your connection will leak water, When I say leak I mean spew water everywhere, so yes you need it.  I’m not going to answer the question until I know exactly all the details about what you’re doing. Supply lines from faucets normally do not go into compression fittings. The compression fitting goes on the supply pipe coming from the wall. You can search YouTube for how to install compression fittings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there may be some misunderstandings here

1. "Sharkbite" is both a brand name AND a trademark for a type of solderless fitting-to-pipe connection.  The connection type came first and fittings using it were branded as "Sharkbite" by the company. They have now branched out into also selling fittings with traditional types of connections (threaded, soldered, etc) and these are also confusingly branded as "Sharkbite".

I believe the OP may have a Sharkbite brand fitting with traditional non-Sharkbite connections. I believe the experts here are referring only to the Sharkbite connection style.

2. Traditional 3/8" compression **connectors** are typical for the outflow from a faucet supply shutoff valve to supply lines running to a faucet.

**If the faucet supply line is (semi-) rigid copper/brass with no connector on its end, the ferrule and nut are necessary** to clamp and seal the line in the compression connector. The nut compresses the soft metal ferrule into the line and fitting, making a watertight seal.  Such rigid connecting lines were common for faucets 50-100 years ago.

In modern US residential sinks, flexible braided faucet supply lines are normally used instead.  To maintain compatibility, the **braided supply line connector ends thread** onto the same male threads of the compression connector **in place of the ferrule and nut**.  They have end connectors that only need to be tightened hand-tight plus maybe 1/4 turn more to make a good seal, because of a rubber seal inside.

**I think the OP** is connecting such a braided supply line to a compression connector on the shutoff valve and so **should NOT use the ferrule and nut shown**, as the braided supply line's connector takes their place.

Answer (score 7):

Here is the correct answer to the question as it is written.

The copper ring is a ferrule, which is part of a compression fitting.

You absolutely need the copper Ferrule for a watertight connection, and plumbers tape is not necessary when this type of connection is installed properly.

If you do not know what a copper Farrule is and what a compression fitting is than you need to learn before you try to install this valve.

I have no way of knowing if you have the correct part for the plumbing task that you are trying to accomplish. If you edit your question with more details and photos then I may be able to help.

Comment: You are absolutely correct that I have no idea what a ferrule is. I do still still that connecting a faucet supply line isn't something that needs much expertise. The disconnection of the old faucet supplies was easy and I don't remember my old valves having ferrules. Here is a photo of the faucet supply connector with the valve in question, hopefully this helps you answer the question with more precision. I do appreciate your responses! https://i.imgur.com/lAI2ek2.jpg

Comment: Based on the photo it appears that you have pushed the shark bite connection side of the valve onto the supply line coming from the wall and you have the faucet supply line coming down to attach to the threaded portion of the valve. The supply line from the faucet has a built-in compression washer inside of it so all you need to do is tighten the supply line on to The valve. You want to tighten the supply line with an adjustable wrench but do not over tighten it as to not over compress the rubber washer. The ferrule is not needed for this connection

Comment: @0pt1m1z3  You would use that ferrule if the lines from your faucet were 3/8" copper just cut off at the end. +